# Visual Studio 2012 everything out of date

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I usually use C# applications, which work fine.  Now that I feel like I have a strong grasp of C#, I've decided to move on to C++.  *I have changed no preferences.* All of my C++ projects say that the project is out of date.  Here are my steps:

1. File -> New Project
2. Click "Visual C++" tab -> Win32 Console Application
3. Change nothing and click OK
4. Click Finish for the Win32 Application Wizard
5. Press F5 to run, or click the button (which says "Local Windows Debugger").
   [image: Error dialog saying 'this project is out of date']
   I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake or if there are missing dependencies.  My question is, what is causing this and how can I prevent this message?  If you don't know, then what are some things that I can do to find out?

Comment: Did you try clicking *Yes*? The program has not been compiled to an executable yet. The *Would you like to build it?* question means *do you want to compile the current source to executable?* before running it.

Comment: And if you click "Do not show this dialog again", then your application will be automatically built when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is causing this

=> Two possible reasons :

- you just created the project and have not built it before trying to launch it
- OR you made some changes to the project files and tried to launch the application before building the project

> how can I prevent this message?

- Tick "Do not show this dialog again" and click yes : your application will automatically be built every time you want to launch it.
- OR always build the project before launching it

Comment: So then what does "out of date" mean?

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... That the generated executable is not in sync with your source files ; so it's "out of date" because it's older that the source and must be regenerated.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... : The message is indeed confusing. In general, out of date means the executable was last built before the most recent change to a source file (i.e. the exe misses at least that change). A missing executable generates the same message, even though it's confusing for that case.